# Central European (Croatian) characters in R terminal

Tags: r, encoding, terminal, special-characters

I am making a project where everyday at startup an R script is executed that checks on a webpage if there is an updated dataset and if so, R knits and republishes an updated .Rmd file.

Everything is ok when using RStudio but when I try to do it from bash, the character encoding is off because it changes Croatian characters (`ščćđž`).

The command prompt is representing them correctly
[Croatian characters in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuP1v.jpg)

However R terminal doesn't
[Croatian characters in R terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWtMl.jpg)

This is an output from Sys.getlocale() and getOption("encoding")
[Locale and encoding info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B55fO.jpg)

What should I do?

Comment: Run `chcp 1250` before invoking `R`. Please, next time, post your [mcve] as **plain text** (formatted as code, of course) **instead of screenshot images**…